# A is equivalent to B & C & D vs. given B & C A is equivalent to D

Tags: logic

Is saying that A is equivalent to B & C & D the same as saying that given B & C A is equivalent to D? In other terms, I'm just asking whether A ⇔ B & C & D is equivalent to the following: assuming B & C, A ⇔ D. I would say yes, but I wouldn't really be able to explain why.

Comment: What does this even mean?

Comment: So, there is a fundamental error in the presented representation.

Do you mean 
$A \Leftrightarrow B \& C \& D$ ?

or 

Do you mean 
$A \Leftrightarrow B  \&   A \Leftrightarrow C \&   A \Leftrightarrow D   $ ?

Comment: I'm just asking whether A ⇔ B & C & D is equivalent to the following: assuming B & C, A ⇔ D

Comment: No.  A equivalent to B&C&D means you can't have A if you don't have all three B,C,&D.  But given B&C then A equivalent to D means you have no idea if A$ is possible without both B and C.

Comment: Suppose $A$ is true and $B$ is false. Then the first one comes out False, and the second one comes out True (regardless of truth assignment to $C$ and $D$), since the second one is : $ (B & C) -> (A <-> D)$ and hence comes out true whenever at least one of $B$ or $C$ is false.

Answer (score 0):

If $B$ and $C$ are both true then $A\iff D$ and $A\land (B\land C) \iff D$ and $A \iff D\land (B\land C)$ and $A\land(B\land C)\iff D\land(B\land C)$ are all the same.  They are true if $A$ and $D$ are both true or both false.

But what  if $B$ and $C$ are *not* both true.

$A\iff B\land C \land D$ would mean $A$ is impossible as $B\land C\land D$ is not possible.  But $B\land C; A\iff D$ doesn't allow us do conclude *anything* about $A$ or $D$.  If $B$ or $C$ is false then $B\land C; A\iff D$ would be vacuously true always.  But $A \iff B\land C\land D$ would be vacuously true only if $A$ is false.

Truth tables:

There Four cases where $BC=11$ then we have $A\iff B\land C\land D$ and $B\land C; A\iff D$ are in agreement:

$BCAD =$

$1111: A\iff B\land C\land D=1; B\land C; A\iff D=1$

$1110: A\iff B\land C\land D=0; B\land C; A\iff D=0$

$1101: A\iff B\land C\land D=0; B\land C; A\iff D=0$

$1100: A\iff B\land C\land D=1; B\land C; A\iff D=1$

But the $12$ cases where $B\land C = 0$ then $B\land C; A\iff D$ is always true but $A\iff B\land C\land D$ is true only if $A$ is false

If $BC = xx = 10|01|00$ then

$BCAD =$

$xx11: A\iff B\land C\land D=0; B\land C; A\iff D=1$

$xx10: A\iff B\land C\land D=0; B\land C; A\iff D=1$

$xx01: A\iff B\land C\land D=1; B\land C; A\iff D=1$

$xx00: A\iff B\land C\land D=1; B\land C; A\iff D=1$

That makes $10$ cases were the statements are the same but $6$ where they are not.

====old and wordy====

A equivalent to B&C&D means that if you have A you always have B,C,D, and if you don't have all B,C and D then A is impossible.

Given B&C then A is equivalent to D, meand that if you have B&C then you know, if you have A&B&C you always have D, and if you don't have D then have A while having B and C is impossible.

These aren't the same.

$A\iff B\land C\land D$

makes the 7 cases where $A$ is true but not all $B,C,D$ are true impossible.  It also makes the 1 case where $A$ is false and all $B,C,D$ are true impossible.  And it allows for the $1$ case where $A,B,C,D$ are all true and for the 7 cases where $A$ is false and $B,C,D$ not  all true.

But $B\land C: A\iff D$ allows for all $12$ cases where $B$ and $C$ are not true to happen no matter what. This include $6$ cases where $A$ is true. None of these 6 cases were allowed above.

Basically:  $A\iff B\land C\land D$ and $B\land C; A\iff D$ are both true if $ABCD=1111;0110;0101;0100;0011;0010, 0001, 0000$

$A\iff B\land C\land D$ and $B\land C; A\iff D$ are both false if $ABCD=0111;1110$.

$A\iff B\land C\land D$ is false and $B\land C; A\iff D$ is true if

$ABCD=1101;1100;1011;1010;1001;1000$

$A\iff B\land C\land D$ is true and $B\land C; A\iff D$ is false never happens.